# Can I connect via Bluetooth(or USB) to a device sitting locally at my desk from the App running on Test-Cloud?

Tags: bluetooth, xamarin-test-cloud

I work with POS devices. We have a cross-platform mobile Xamarin App which talks to POS devices using Bluetooth or USB.It would be a great help if you can do that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. It is possible to run Xamarin.UITests on locally connected devices as described in this guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/testing-on-devices/

That would *not* be running on the Test Cloud though. If your question relates to testing some communication feature of your app, so that you're connecting from the Test Cloud to locally then I don't think it's directly possible; but you could simulate the behavior by using a backdoor: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/working-with/backdoors/

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot, unfortunately the only way to interact with any device needed by the mobile client is through web requests. Unfortunately this is limited because no 1 BLE solution would work for everyone (actually it would only work for very few).

Another challenge is that the automated UI tests will run in the order determined by Xamarin Test Cloud and you may potentially have multiple devices interacting with your one device.

You could do this all locally though on your own device. You would just trigger the [UITest locally through the command line](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/cheatsheet/#Running_UITests_Using_the_Command_Line) and have the BLE device by your phone. I know this isn't ideal, but really one of your best options here.

The other option you have is creating a middle-man for your POS devices. Basically the middleman would be a REST API hosted on some IoT device that contains BLE integration. You would than have to forward the BLE requests from the IoT device to your POS device, but this solution would require larger time frames for the data to transfer and wouldn't necessarily be a "real-world" testing scenario. I would expect that you would have some false failure tests due to the details with creating this solution. I have done something similar for Particle, but I was only able to run UI Tests on 1 device at a time.

Disclosure: I work for Xamarin/Microsoft.